# 405 Method Not Allowed - Dynamics GP 2010 Web Service

Tags: wcf, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-gp

I am trying to access my client's GP 2010 web service, but I get this error:

The request failed with `HTTP status 405: Method Not Allowed`.

The URL is `http://www.xyz.com:48620/Dynamics/GPService`

In Visual Studio, I see this URL in the add web reference box:

> xyz:48620/Metadata/WCF/Full/schemas.microsoft.com.dynamics.gp.2010.01.wsdl

When I visit the URL in the browser, I can see the WSDL:

[image]

Here is the WSDL code:

http://pastebin.com/0VU7ZRbE

The customer has installed the GP2010 web service and it appears in the browser. I cannot add a reference to it in Visual Studio. The customer has added an inbound and an outbound firewall rule.

Am I using the wrong URL or is there something else to install?

Comment: Can you see the WSDL of the above service? Please post the code that shows your connection to the service?

Comment: Thanks. I added more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a web reference, you add localhost:48620/Dynamics/GPService . If you need to authenticate to another one, add change the URL:

```
 // Create an instance of the service
        DynamicsGP.Core.DynamicsGPService.DynamicsGP wsDynamicsGP = new DynamicsGP.Core.DynamicsGPService.DynamicsGP();
        wsDynamicsGP.Url = "http://www.mysite.com:48620/DynamicsGPWebServices/DynamicsGPService.asmx";
        // Be sure the default credentials are used
        wsDynamicsGP.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        wsDynamicsGP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");

        CompanyCriteria cc = new CompanyCriteria();
        Company[] c = wsDynamicsGP.GetCompanyList(cc, new Context());


        return wsDynamicsGP;
```